# Problem "upgrading" from Xenial to Wily

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

A week or so ago I decided to do the usual weekly upgrade to my Wily Werewolf 15.10, but this time it asked "would you like to upgrade to 16.04 Xenial?" 
Sure. Why not? Hey, finally an new LTS! It was late at night, and I was going to bed. The upgrade was supposed to take a couple of hours - perhaps 4 hours at most.

i.e., The usual stuff -I've been upgrading like this since Ubuntu 6.04 or so... So I went to bed and let it do its thing.

Next morning -about 12 hours later -(as a retiree, I get up late!) the Electric power utility clicked off once or twice at 10AM. Sadly, this desktop is not on a UPS. Yet!

When I finally got around to checking the upgrade, it was in a weird state:
Half of it appears to be 16.04 Xenial and half is the older 15.10 Wily.
Now, when I try to do a upgrade, it eventually says "partial upgrade possible"... and then eventually tells me:
"An upgrade from Xenial to Wily is not possible with this tool."

Any suggestions on how I can proceed / backout / correct this problem? 
Thanx. 
   -Tony

Sent at 1AM Tuesday; I'll be  compos-mentis once again later today at approx 1100 -1300 hrs.
PC: Phenom-X2-560,with one TB WD-Blue disk  which dual boots Ubuntu 15.10 and Win-10 Preview Build 14328. Need I say, it's my "test" PC, not the production one! ;-)

Comment: Phew hard one, i would suggest using live CD/USB and external HDD to backup files and so on and do a clean install, propably will the less troublesome way to go.

Comment: Thanx, Videonauth- 
I started to do that yesterday, but the DL of  Xenial 1604,said 10 hours to completion! 
I live in a rural log cabin in the deep dark woods and have a satellite connection, supposedly 5 Mbs, but as always,"your results may differ")
Perhaps I'll fire  up the DL again, and go to bed now... LOL -  with my luck  the power will probably fail again in middle of the night. Or a meteorite will crash into the bird...